# Unable to view the contents of file in ansible managed nodes

Tags: plugins, view, ansible, lookup

I'm trying to view the contents of a file from managed node and control node, here I see the syntax works fine for localhost (172.17.254.200) but not for the remote hosts. Below is the task I have written using lookup / query plugin, can you please suggest the fix:

```
---
- name: Report Test
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - patching
  tasks:
    - name: Display the Pre and Post check Differences
      debug:
        msg: "{{ query('file', '/tmp/check/{{ inventory_hostname }}_Comparison') }}"
```

Below is the output

```
TASK [patching : Display the Pre and Post check Differences] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.17.254.200] =>
  msg:
  - |-
    free_m - YES
    sysctl_all - YES
    uptime - YES
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/tmp/check/172.17.254.207_Comparison' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

fatal: [172.17.254.207]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin ''file''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /tmp/check/172.17.254.207_Comparison'
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/tmp/check/172.17.254.208_Comparison' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

fatal: [172.17.254.208]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin ''file''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /tmp/check/172.17.254.208_Comparison'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookups are executed on Ansible controller (as pointed out by @Vladimir Botka). If you just want to *view the contents* of a file on remote hosts, you can `cat` the file through ansible and debug the `stdout_lines`.

```yaml
  - command: "cat /tmp/check/{{ inventory_hostname }}_Comparison"
    register: file_cat
    changed_when: false

  - debug:
      var: file_cat.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

[*lookup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) and *query* *"execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine."*

Use [*slurp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html#ansible-builtin-slurp-slurps-a-file-from-remote-nodes). Quoting:

> This module returns an ‘in memory’ base64 encoded version of the file, take into account that this will require at least twice the RAM as the original file size.

For larger files use [*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#ansible-builtin-fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes). Quoting:

> It is used for fetching files from remote machines and storing them locally in a file tree, organized by hostname.